# XSS Attack for Modifying the URL

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, xss

One of our client has reported XSS issue on our application saying that we are not sanitizing the request values. He has directly added a script in the browser and it executed as alert message.

Here is the sample URL:

```
https://domain.com?tool=param1&toolName=param2&category=param3&locale=param4&currency=HH&theme=Theme"/><script>alert(1)</script>
```

In the above URL, at the end script tag is added with alert message. Is that correct way of testing XSS attack? Why he has to directly modify the URL and test it.

If that is correct, how can I fix the issue by adding some client side scripts. The server side framework is Spring MVC.

### Update:

Can I use c:out tage to prevent this attack? I am using JSP pages and JSTL tage in it.

Comment: Yes, this is the _one_ of the correct ways of testing for XSS

Comment: Whether or not c:out can used depends on in which context the XSS occurs. Please refer to the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet: 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about XSS, but this may happen if you assign to a `dom` element as `html` the value that you read from your querystring directly (or from a not validated textbox). You can just encode the url or the url params:

```
var param = encodeURIComponent(paramFromQueryString);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just get rid of the issue with a `CSP` Header - see https://content-security-policy.com/ and not enabled `script-src directive'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval'. which would be a quick work around.

However you should try remove the injection of that query string in to the page without html escaping the whole content. Without having the code that the server is rendering it's hard to advise what needs to change.

Comment: This problem should be fixed at the root. CSP is intended as an extra safeguard, and for many websites it's probably harder to add CSP than to fix the given problem, because inline script is already in use.

Comment: _which would be a quick work around._ and _However you should try remove the injection of that query string_ explains that in the answer...